# Saving bar plot/ Histogram in excel

Tags: python, dataframe

```
for p, hc in enumerate(sheet2,1):
    histo=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name=f'Histogram{p}')
    plot=histo.plot(kind='bar')
    plt.xlabel("Probe Name")
    plt.ylabel("Fold Change")
```

I have read this excel of 3 sheets containing data and created plot. Now I want to save these 3 plots in the same excel, same sheets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at pd.excelwriter. I would try something like this

```
for p, hc in enumerate(sheet2,1):
    histo=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name=f'Histogram{p}')
    plot=histo.plot(kind='bar')
    plt.xlabel("Probe Name")
    plt.ylabel("Fold Change")
    
  
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    plot.savefig(path, sheet_name=f'Histogram{p}')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: NameError: name 'book' is not defined